# Two Bundles with netty4-http one server and one client serve loads client doesn't

Tags: apache-camel, netty4

The client camel context that follows loads and runs just fine. This atomic service accepts requests from other bundles via dicrect-vm to connect to an external REST server.

```
<camelContext id="_camuatomicservicecontext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="_camuatomicserviceroute1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="direct-vm:camuatomicservice">
                <description>accepts vm messages directly </description>
            </from>
            <log id="_log1" message="Camu Atomic Service body = ${body}, header= ${header.uriPattern}"/>
            <setHeader headerName="api.key" id="_setHeader1">
                <constant>"9GC1hnEeNIWVbehmxxjUwkj1Wcx2Y-P7SgOUZvVUzkM"</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath" id="_setHeader1">
                <simple>${header.uriPattern}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod" id="_setHeader2">
                <simple>${header.CamelHttpMethod}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <to id="_to1" pattern="InOut" uri="netty4-http:http:{{camu.host}}:{{camu.port}}/{{camu.path}}?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
            <log id="_log2" message="CamuAtomicService Response body ${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

So I wanted a mockup API to test with.  I created the following context in another bundle for testing.  But it refuses to start. I read in the documentation that netty4-http components on same host and port must have same configuration.  But it still won't start.

```
<camelContext id="_camumockcontext1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="_camumockroute1">
            <from id="_from1" pattern="InOut" uri="netty4-http:http:localhost:8288/external?matchOnUriPrefix=true">
                <description>Mock the Camu API</description>
            </from>
            <process id="_process1" ref="CogMockProcessor"/>
            <log id="_log1" message="Made it here CamuMock headers = ${headers}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

I tried log:set DEBUG but didn't see anything related to this bundle in hawtio

Answer (score 0):

The cause was a port conflict with another bundle.  However, although I had changed the port in the blueprint and properties, and committed to my local git repo, the build didn't update the jar file and that meant the port wasn't changing to match the source.  I went to the target and deleted the jar file and rebuilt and redeployed and it worked.  Lesson learned if the sources look fine, and something doesn't work, double check in hawtio contexts camel that the change you made took effect.